# IIS Deploy - Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I had deployed my 2.0 application in IIS 7. Its a 64 Bit Machine. The application developed in 32 Bit Machine. Once i browse the application i am gettting the error like

```
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
```

How to fix this.. I had searched google, but i dint get any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS manager, go to the app pool settings. Then set 'Allow 32-bit application' to `true`. Restart the app pool or IIS.

Comment: Let me check, I had this same issue 6 months back. Edit: Yes, that was the only change I needed to make.

Comment: IIS App Pool - Framework 2.0 and Enable 32 Bit app - True.. This i had done..but same issue is coming..should i need to restart the IIS.

Comment: @RobinHood: The only difference in my case is running .NET 4 (integrated mode). And yes, restart IIS for good measure :)

Comment: Should i need to change anything in my web.config file

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I had converted the application in 4.0 and put the latest dlls. Now its working fine.

Comment: @RobinHood: That's good to know. Glad you found the solution :)